# Question about Cars: Momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

> **Car B rests at the bottom of a frictionless inclined plane. In order to travel
>   a height of 0.6m and maintain a speed of 2 m/s at the end
>   of the track it needs to start with 4 m/s.**
>
> a) If car B perceives the speed through a fully elastic impact from
>   car A, with what speed does car A have to hit car B if the mass of car A is
>   twice the mass of car B?
>
> b) What's the velocity of car A after the collision?

How I tried to solve it:

a)

$$m_A \cdot v_{A,End} = m_B \cdot v_{B, Beginning}$$

$$2m_B \cdot v_{A,End} = m_B \cdot 4 \frac{m}{s}$$

$$v_{A,End} = 2 \frac{m}{s}$$

Therefore $v_{A}$ has to be 2 $\frac{m}{s}$ when hitting car B.

b)

$$v_{A, End} = \frac{(m_A-m_B) \cdot v_{A, Beginning} + 2 m_B v_{B, Beginning}}{(m_A + m_B)}$$

$$v_{A, End} = \frac{(2m_B-m_B) \cdot 2 \frac{m}{s} + 2 \cdot m_B \cdot 4 \frac{m}{s}}{3 m_B}$$

$$v_{A, End} = \frac{m_B \cdot 2 \frac{m}{s} + 2 \cdot m_B \cdot 4 \frac{m}{s}}{3 m_B}$$

Which gives me 2 $\frac{m}{s}$ to the right.

**According to the solutions, however, I should get $3 \frac{m}{s}$ for a) and $1 \frac{m}{s}$ for b).**

Comment: Why use pulleys when there are no ropes?

Comment: First remark: "if its mass is twice the mass of pulley A" means $m_B = 2m_A$. You've used $m_A = 2m_B$. Second remark: conservation of momentum should be applied by equating the sum of all the momenta *before* with that of all the momenta *after* the collision.

Comment: @user80551 my mistake, sorry... I thought pulleys are little cars as well. The question is not in English and I mistranslated it.
+ @ Wouter Typo. It should read "if mass A is twice the mass of B". I'll edit that. + apart from that; where exactly did I make a mistake?

Comment: You'll also need the angle of inclination of the plane

Comment: @libjup Look at your equation for the conservation of momentum again. There are 4 momenta here: that of A before the collision, that of B before, that of A after and that of B after. You should put all the ones before on one side of the equation and the ones after on the other side, expressing that the total momentum is conserved by the collision.

Comment: @user80551 Not at all.

Comment: Conservation of energy?

Comment: I had also remarked the need for conservation of energy to calculate the speed B would need to have after the collision in order to reach 0.6 m and still have a speed of 2 m/s. When I reread the question (which gives that speed) I removed it, but @neutrino is right: you do still need to apply conservation of energy.

Comment: I actually do have the solutions for 1) here but they were not clear to me:

v_B,End = 2 * (m_A*v_A,Beginning)/(m_A+m_B) = 2/3 * v_A,Beginning

v_B,End = 4/3 * V_A,Beginning

v_A,Beginning = 3/4 * v_B,End = 3/4 * 4 = 3m/s;

They were using the formula for an inelastic collision. However, it clearly states "elastic collision" in the question....

Comment: I wouldn't focus on the solutions you have in front of you. Just try doing what I said: equate the sum of all the momenta before the collision to the sum of those after the collision. (one of the momenta is zero, which one?) And do the same thing for all the energies before and (immediately) after the collision. (there are only kinetic energies in play here) You should then have two equations for two unknown variables: the speed of mass A before the collision and the speed of A after.

Comment: Did you manage to work out the solution? And (perhaps more importantly) do you see why you didn't get there before?

Comment: Yes I indeed did. Thank you all for your support. Thomas Fan kindly posted a solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u_a$ and $u_b$ be the final velocities of car a and b respectively, and let $v_a$ be the initially velocity of car a. The conservation of momentum that the final momentum is the same as the initial momentum (if there isn't any external forces):
$$
m_av_a=m_au_a+m_bu_b
\tag1
$$
Since this is an fully elastic impact, the energy is conserved:
$$
\dfrac{1}{2}m_av_a^2=\dfrac{1}{2}m_au_a^2+\dfrac{1}{2}m_bu_b^2
\tag2
$$
With some algebra:
$$
m_av_a^2=m_au_a^2+m_bu_b^2\\
m_av_a^2-m_au_a^2=m_bu_b^2\\
m_a(v_a^2-u_a^2)=m_bu_b^2\\
$$
Eq(2) becomes:
$$
m_a(v_a-u_a)(v_a+u_a)=m_bu_b^2
\tag3
$$
Here one uses $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$. Eq(1) can be rewritten as:
$$
m_a(v_a-u_a)=m_bu_b
\tag4
$$
Eq(4) can be inserted into Eq(3) to get:
$$
m_bu_b(v_a+u_a)=m_bu_b^2
$$
or
$$
v_a+u_b=u_b
\tag5
$$
Plugging in that $m_a=2m_b$ and $u_b=4$ into Eq(1) and Eq(5) yields two equations:
$$
v_a+u_a=4
\tag6
$$
$$
2v_a=2u_a+4
\tag7
$$
Eq(7) can be simplify to
$$
v_a=u_a+2
\tag8
$$
Plugging in Eq(8) into Eq(6) gives:
$$
2u_a+2=4
$$
which gives the result $u_a=1$ m/s. Plugging $u_a$ into Eq(8) gives $v_a=3$ m/s.